# Oracle set based insert vs set based merge performance

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

We're using Oracle 11g at the moment without Enterprise (not an option unfortunately).

Let's say I have a table with a constant(Let's say 2000) rows of data. Let's call it data_source.

I want to insert some columns of this table into another table, data_dest. I'm using all the records from the source table.

In other words, I would like to insert this set

```
select data_source.col1, data_source.col2, ... data_source.colN 
from data_source
```

Which would be faster in this case:

```
insert into data_dest
  select data_source.col1, data_source.col2, ... data_source.colN 
  from data_source
```

OR

```
merge into data_dest dd
  using data_source ds
  on (dd.col1 = ds.col1) --Let's assume that this is a matching column names
  when not matched
    insert (col1,col2...)
    values(ds.col1,ds.col2...)
```

EDIT 1:
We can assume there are no primary keys violations from the insert.
In other words we can assume that insert will successfully insert all of the rows and so will merge.

Comment: Please run: `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR the_first_query_insert`, and then `SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.Display )`. FInally copy a result of second query **as a text, not bitmap** - using simple "copy-paste" and append it to the question. Next repeat the above steps for the second query ... `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR the_second_query_merge` etc. etc.

Comment: @krokodilko yeah insert seems to be way faster

Comment: @krokodilko that's a nice tuning technique, thank you.

Comment: Given your assumption the straight INSERT is the only option. The value of MERGE is to handle key clashes in a nice fashion. That said, the time difference between the two approaches is likely to be negligible for 2000 rows. So not worth worrying about unless you intend to do this *a lot*.

Comment: @Tim Zhukov-Khovanskiy the explain-plan is only a piece of tuning techniques, if you want more please study this link: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/toc.htm Explain plans are described in `Part III Query Execution Plans` of this guide

Comment: @APC It's actually a part of data generation procedure that creates a few million rows usually. My current setup is mark all non-unique indexes unusable and turn off constraints, then create the data in temp table with connect by and then insert it into the corresponding tables. I just wanted to see what other techniques I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `insert` is very likely faster because it does not require a join on the two tables.

That said, the two queries are not equivalent. Assuming that `col1` is defined as the primary key, the `insert` will throw an error if `data_source` contains a value in `col1` that is already in `data_dest`. Because the `merge` is comparing the data in the two tables, then only inserting only the rows that don't already exist, it won't ever throw a primary key violation.

An `insert` that would be equivalent to the `merge` would be:

```
INSERT INTO data_dest
   SELECT data_source.col1, data_source.col2, ... data_source.colN
   FROM   data_source
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS
             (SELECT *
              FROM   data_dest
              WHERE  data_source.col1 = data_dest.col1)
```

It's likely that the plan for this `insert` will be very similar (if not identical) to the plan for the `merge` and the performance would be indistinguishable.

Comment: thank you, we can assume that the data is non-repeated.

Comment: In that case there's no point in using the `merge`. It'll run the comparison anyhow (because the engine doesn't know the data being inserted is unique), which is a waste of resources.